# Efficent way in TensorFlow to subtract mean and divide by standard deivation for each row

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape `[x, y]` and I want to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation row-wise (i.e. I want to do it for each row). What is the most efficient way to do this in TensorFlow?

Of course I can loop through rows as follows:

```
new_tensor = [i - tf.reduce_mean(i) for i in old_tensor]
```

...to subtract the mean and then do something similar to find the standard deviation and divide by it, but is this the best way to do it in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The TensorFlow `tf.sub()` and `tf.div()` operators support broadcasting, so you don't need to iterate through every row. Let's consider the mean, and leave standard deviation as an exercise:

```
old_tensor = ...                                          # shape = (x, y)
mean = tf.reduce_mean(old_tensor, 1, keep_dims=True)      # shape = (x, 1)                    

stdev = ...                                               # shape = (x,)
stdev = tf.expand_dims(stdev, 1)                          # shape = (x, 1)

new_tensor = old_tensor - mean                            # shape = (x, y)
new_tensor = old_tensor / stdev                           # shape = (x, y)
```

The subtraction and division operators implicitly broadcast a tensor of shape `(x, 1)` along the column dimension to match the shape of the other argument, `(x, y)`. For more details about how broadcasting works, see the [NumPy documentation on the topic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) (TensorFlow implements NumPy broadcasting semantics).

Answer (score 9):

1. calculate moments along axis 1 (y in your case) and keep dimensions, i.e. shape of mean and var is (len(x), 1)
2. subtract mean and divide by standard deviation (i.e. square root of variance)

```
mean, var = tf.nn.moments(old_tensor, [1], keep_dims=True)
new_tensor = tf.div(tf.subtract(old_tensor, mean), tf.sqrt(var))
```